# Why is calling refresh on PagingDataAdapter Not working in Paging 3

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-3

Hello? I'm trying to implement paging by using Paging 3 Library and pull to refresh with SwipeRefreshLayout but calling refresh on paging data adapter instance not taking effect. `load` method of `RemoteMediator` never gets called. Only works the app starts for the first time but, after the app starts no matter how many times I pull to refresh the load method  is not working. You can see the code here
[Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2LQk.png)

[ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX3r8.png)

[Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CRZr.png)

[RemoteMediator Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRqw8.png)

[RemoteMediator Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olKlb.png)

[RemoteMediator Part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fnUr.png)

[RemoteMediator Part 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWxQ.png)

[RemoteMediator Part 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MI2N.png)

please help me?
Note I'm using version 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.1'

Comment: It is good practice to add your code using the code snippet not using the image, it is better to read and can help others to copy your code and debug it.

Comment: Ok that is good to know. thanks